# off shore or off the shore and use of "the"

Tags: articles

> 1. We had a couple of hours on shore.
> 2. The island is about three miles off shore.
> 3. Rubbish of all sorts is washed up on the shore.

Why did we not use *the* in the first and second sentences? Aren't there already a specific place in the sentences?

Comment: [*Offshore*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offshore) is a single word. (As is [*onshore*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onshore).) When used as a preposition, it's synonymous with *off the shore of*.

Comment: When you are "on shore" you have disembarked from the boat and are **on land** which might or might not be its shore. The washed up rubbish really is on the shore of the island, it can't be "washed up" inland.

Comment: @JasonBassford _On shore_ and _off shore_ don't _have_ to be written as one word, at least in my British English. As Weather Vane says, _on shore_ implies having disembarked from a boat, while _on the shore_ = at the beach.

Answer (score 1):

Offshore = off shore = off the shore

Onshore = on shore = on the shore

Basically, they were phrases that were used so commonly they become words of their own.